# How can I get the errors of my form into a string in Symfony 4?

Tags: forms, symfony, render

I am trying to output the errors from a form:

```
  ->getForm();
  $form->handleRequest($request);
  if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($item, $item->getPlainPassword());
    $item->setPassword($password);
    $item = $form->getData();
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($item);
    $entityManager->flush();
    return $this->redirectToRoute('pages', array(
      'slug' => $slug,
    ));
  } else {
    $errors = $form->getErrors();
  }


 return $this->render('list.html.twig', ['errors' => $errors,'form' => $form->createView()]);
```

in my list.html.twig I try to output it like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Symfony{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1>{{ form_errors(form) }}</h1>


         <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            {{ form_end(form) }}
          </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

{{ parent() }}

{% endblock %}
```

But I do not see the errors, even Symfony is telling me in the Profiler that there are errors.

Comment: Did you start in your template `{{ form_start(form) }}`? Or can you post your list.html.twig?

Comment: @M.Kebza I updated the code

Comment: the error is displayed in the the form-group. But I need it seperately

Comment: I happy for every idea!

Comment: Try to move `form_start` before `form_errors`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a separate error per field you would need to do like this:

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.age) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.age) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.age) }}
    {{ form_help(form.age) }}
</div>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)

Based on your Entity your form rendering would be like this

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.username) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
    {{ form_help(form.username) }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_help(form.plainPassword.first) }}
</div>
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ form_help(form.plainPassword.second) }}
</div>
```

That's based on your entity and would be counted as a login form of course you have to add the other fields based on  your requirements a button and some html or you can use the form theme for bs3 or bs4 etc.
Search the manual you will find more info.
Also you should edit your post and add your entity there and html twig.

Comment: Tested it, but I do not see any errors. Where does "age" come from? Is this the name of the entity?

Comment: in the above example age comes from entity. if in your entity you would have $age then in your formType class yo would have in the builder that field. and  that means when you create a view for your form and you load the twig you can access there using form.variable_name

Comment: So this is how I create the form `$item = new User();` Do I use then `{{ form_label(form.User) }}`?

Comment: No. Post your entity & form class and i will show you an example

Comment: list.html.twig: https://textuploader.com/dz382 User.php: https://textuploader.com/dz38v PagesController.php: https://textuploader.com/dz38n I like to display the errors not at the place of the forms, I want to display it at the place of `{{page.name}}`